# OSError: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions while running in PyCharm environment

Tags: python, flask, pycharm

Installed PyCharm for evaluation. When trying to run a "Hello World" Flask application:

```
from flask import Flask
import os
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, use_debugger=False, use_reloader=False, passthrough_errors=True)
```

Getting error:

> OSError: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Error occurred in socketserver.py file

> File "C:\Python371\lib\socketserver.py", line 463, in server_bind
>       self.socket.bind(self.server_address)

I used netstat utility and saw that port that application is trying to use '5555' is not in use. I tryed to run PyCharm as Administrator, but still same problem exists. Note: Same project when opened in Visual Studio 2017 works without any problems. Am I missing some configuration in PyCharm?

Comment: Can you change port ?

Comment: Yes, Several times port was changed. Tried 8080, 8181, 2526, 3030 - same error

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution for the above problem. It may happen that the port 5000 is already in use. You can check the same by running this command in admin command prompt

```
netstat -ano | findstr portNo
```

You will be able to see list of active tasks on that port and you can close all unnecessary task by using this command

```
taskkill /f /pid 5164
```

**replace 5164** with the pid you see after running the earlier command.
After this restart your server.